# How to make the side bar active?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a side bar using Bootsrap CSS, but the class=" active" does not work.

Here , the tab Add is not active by default.
Could you please let me know how to make Add active by default when using `class="nav nav-sidebar"`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Add </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">View/Modify</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please find below working link:
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/shlpj35/em9bznq7/1/#&togetherjs=JD9J1OiPuz)

Comment: easy fix would be adding a css style for `li.active`

Comment: Is there nothing we can do using Bootstrap by default without writing extra code ?

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: Have a look on [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to let it know how you'd like it to look once it's active. And you need a little jquery to do the active swapping for you.

So here I've added the jquery, I've styled li.active (I also styles li a little so I could us the underline example)

Your html is the same though.

```js
$(".nav a").on("click", function() {
  $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.nav li {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.nav li:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
}
.nav li.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #338ecf;
  background: #eee
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Add </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">View/Modify</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution

Comment: This works well because you are not redirecting user to any route/link(# for href). In real time, we might want user to navigate to some other route keeping same sidebar.
In that case, this code won't work because when user is redirected to some page, the sidebar will load again and active class will be applied to first `<li>` again, and this repeats for each navigation/user click.
Can you suggest any solution for this @Andrew Bone?

Answer (score 3):

I check your code and added some classes. check this out. [DEMO here!](https://jsfiddle.net/da2fo6sk/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active"><a href="#">Add </a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">View/Modify</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    li.list-group-item a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

li.list-group-item.active a {
  color: #fff;
}

li.list-group-item.active a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.list-group-item.active, .list-group-item.active:focus, .list-group-item.active:hover {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the background color of the active tab grey instead of blue?
And the text color as black?